# Is there a way to fix shape mismatch issue?

Tags: python, numpy

I am using an array of indexes, but the code below is throwing an error;

IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,9) (9,) (2,3)

```
 data = {'Name': ['Tom Seyer', 'Joseph kabila junior', 'Krish 
 happy cote ivoir', 'John'], 'Age': [20, 21, 19, 18]}  

 df = pd.DataFrame(data)  

 batch_size=2
 vocab_size=2
 max_len=3
 n_samples = len(df['Name'])
 seq_len = len(df['Name'][0])
 X=df['Name']
 Y=df['Age']
 start = 0       
 stop = start + batch_size
 index_3 = X[start: stop]
 tokenizer.fit_on_texts(index_3)
 tokenizer.word_index['BLANK_WORD'] = 0
 index_3 = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(index_3)
 index_3 = sequence.pad_sequences(index_3, maxlen=max_len)
 X_out = np.zeros([batch_size, seq_len, vocab_size])
 print(X_out.shape)
 index_1 = np.repeat(np.arange(batch_size), 
 seq_len).reshape(batch_size, seq_len)
 index_2 = np.arange(seq_len)
 X_out[index_1, index_2, index_3] = 1
```

The first two indexes work fine, but when I add the third one, it throws the error. Is there a different way to do this without error?

Comment: Could you post the output of `print(X_out.shape)`?

Comment: Since the code above gives an error, I cannot  print(X_out.shape), but the X_out.shape for index_1 and index_2 is (2,9,2)

Comment: You can print out the shape before the error is hit, i.e., on the line before that given in you question. Or, just show us how `X_out` is initialised.

Comment: I just add the full code. X_out shape is (2,9,2)

Comment: why is `index_3` shaped (2,3)?  When use index arrays they have to `broadcast` together.  Explain why it is calculated that way.

Comment: Do you understand why array with shape (2,3) doesn't' work  with the others in ` (2,9) (9,) (2,3)`?

Comment: No, I don't, that is what I want to find out.

Comment: If you can't explain what and why `tokenizer` generates this (2,3) array, we can't help you create a broadcastable version.  You may need to read more basic numpy to learn how broadcasting is used in `advanced indexing`.